# How to add threshold line when there are multiple graphs?

Tags: r

I am using a function which plots two graphs on the same picture. I want to add threshold line to the first graph and a different threshold on the second graph. I am using `abline()` function to do so. `chr6` comes with a library as an example.

```
install.packages("GenWin")
library(GenWin)
chrom_num = 6
jpeg(filename = paste(chrom_num, ".jpg", sep=""), width = 1200, height = 800)
chr = splineAnalyze(chr6$Fst, chr6$Position, plotRaw = 1, plotWindows = 1, method = 4)
abline(0.3, 0, col = "green")
abline(6, 0, col = "green")
```

Both threshold lines show up on the second graph. How to prevent this? In other word is there a way to direct to which graph I am adding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add something, I think it would be better to make graphs by yourself from the analyzed data, `chr` (almost all code is picked out from `splineAnalyze`). This approach would enable you to customize the graph.

```
analyzed_data <- chr   # All you need to do is changing these lines and data and col names of 1st plot()).
smoothness <- 100      # default value

jpeg(filename = paste("file_name", ".jpg", sep=""), width = 1200, height = 800)

par(mfrow = c(2,1))

  # 1st graph
plot(Fst ~ Position, chr6, xlab = "Position (bp)", ylab = "Raw values")
with(analyzed_data, 
  lines(x = seq(0, max(rawSpline$x), by = smoothness), 
        y = predict(rawSpline, seq(0, max(rawSpline$x), by = smoothness)), col = "red")
)
abline(0.3, 0, col = "green")

  # 2nd graph
with(analyzed_data,  
  plot(x = (windowData$WindowStop - windowData$WindowStart)/2 + windowData$WindowStart, 
       y = windowData$Wstat, xlab = "Position (bp)", ylab = "Spline Wstat", pch = 19)
)
abline(6, 0, col = "green")

dev.off()
```

Of course, you can do it using `splineAnalyze(..., plotRaw = 1, plotWindows = 1, ...)` and adding the lines.

```
jpeg(filename = paste("file_name2", ".jpg", sep=""), width = 1200, height = 800)

chr = splineAnalyze(chr6$Fst, chr6$Position, plotRaw = 1, plotWindows = 1, method = 4)

abline(6, 0, col = "green")  # draw on 2nd panel
layout(matrix(c(2,1), ncol = 1))                          # refocus 1st panel
par(new = T)
plot(Fst ~ Position, chr6, ann = F, type = "n", axes = F) # reproduce the coordinates
abline(0.3, 0, col = "green") # draw on 1st panel

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used the second way. How did you access the source code of a function?

Comment: @YKY; You can get it by `splineAnalyze` (When you run function without `()`, it returns the code)